# Converting littleEndian via QDataStream

Tags: c++, networking, integer, qt5, qdatastream

i want to send some integers (int32_t) via network.

For this I convert the integers first and send them.

```
p.x = 129;
p.y = 42;
p.d = counter++;

converted[0] = htonl(p.x);
converted[1] = htonl(p.y);
converted[2] = htonl(p.d);
if ( (bytes = send(socket, (char *)converted, pointSize, 0)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "bytes = " << bytes << std::endl;
        }
```

Then Qt should do the work, so I tried a QDataStream conversion but that failed, values > 128 got negative. So currently I do a conversion like this:

```
   while ( socket->bytesAvailable() > 0 )
   {
       //qDebug() << "Data received" << socket->bytesAvailable();
       m_data.append(socket->readAll());
       //qDebug() << "Buffer " << m_data.size();
       if (m_data.size() >= sizeOfPoint)
       {
           Point x;
           QByteArray b = m_data.left(sizeOfPoint);
           for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           {
               x.x += (u_int8_t) b[i] << 8*(3-i);
           }
           for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
           {
               x.y += (u_int8_t) b[i] << 8*(7-i);
           }
           for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++)
           {
               x.d += (u_int8_t) b[i] << 8*(11-i);
           }

           //x.x = (u_int8_t) (b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | (b[3]);
           //x.y = (b[4] << 24) | (b[5] << 16) | (b[6] << 8) | (b[7]);
           //x.d = (b[8] << 24) | (b[9] << 16) | (b[10] << 8) | b[11];
           //x.d = b[10] << 8;
           //x.d = (b[11]);

           //QDataStream in(buffer.data());
           //in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
           //in >> conv[1];
           //in >> conv[2];

           qDebug() << "Data provided " << x.x << " " << x.y << " "<< x.d;
            m_data.remove(0, sizeOfPoint);
       }
   }
```

What is the best way to convert these integers, the for loop seems not optimal for me.

Thank you

Comment: where do you call `ntohl` to convert the received variables back?

Comment: i tried something like x.x = ntohl( (b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | (b[3])); but without the expected result. Had hoped that the QDataStream::LittleEndian would work and that datastream >> (quint32) conv[0] would convert 4 bytes into a 32 bit, but it didn*t